# Configure Eclipse to work with ROS and OpenCV

Tags: ros, opencv, ide, eclipse

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to configure Eclipse Luna to work with ROS and OpenCV?

I followed the [ROS IDE instrucitions](http://wiki.ros.org/IDEs#Eclipse) and I have succesfully set up an eclipse project. On the [OpenCV website](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html#linux-eclipse-usage) in step 8 they tell to click on **Settings** in **C/C++ Build** tab. Unfortunately in my ROS project I don't have such an option. The picture shows the properties window of my project.[image: Properties window of my ROS project]

If I create a new project in Eclipse the **C/C++ Build** tab is where it should be.

**How can I add OpenCV headers and libraries to my ROS project?**

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/204924/configure-eclipse-to-work-with-ros-and-opencv/) by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 141 on 2015-03-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Shouldn't the OpenCV include paths (because the libraries are not used in Eclipse) be added to your Eclipse project automatically if you have your package dependencies setup correctly (ie: you state your OpenCV dependency in your pkg manifest)?

---

Edit: I should've said: "you state your OpenCV dependency in your pkg <del>manifest</del> `CMakeLists.txt`".

The Eclipse project file generator only works with the information in the `CMakeLists.txt`, so you need to add it there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2015-03-13**:
I have such declaration in my package.xml file:  `<build_depend>opencv2</build_depend> <run_depend>opencv2</run_depend>` but `#include <cv.h>` produces an unresolved inclusion

**Comment by [grzebyk](https://answers.ros.org/users/3912/grzebyk/) on 2015-03-13**:
It works. Thank you! I followed [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_gcc_cmake/linux_gcc_cmake.html) and adapted it to ROS.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-03-13**:
The 'official' ROS docs are at [vision_opencv](http://wiki.ros.org/vision_opencv). But they seem similar enough to what you did.